# select box data with apostrophe not submit in database

Tags: php, mysqli

If I input `acesr'ss` as `categoryname` in my POST-Request, it will insert only `acesr` into my database. I can't figure out why.

Relevant code snippet:

```
$cate_name=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['categoryname']);

$usersql="Insert INTO abc(category_name) VALUES('".$cate_name."')";
```

I also tried `addslashes`, but get the same problem.

Comment: `echo $cate_name` name and see what the output

Comment: use this code `$cate_name=htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['categoryname']));`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to insert using parameterised sql query.this will prevent sql injection

```
$dmessage = html_entity_decode ($cate_name, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8') ;
$createSql = $db->prepare(" INSERT INTO abc(category_name) VALUES(:cate_name)" );
$createSql->execute(array(
                        ":cate_name" => trim($cate_name)
                    ));
```

Comment: Neither use `html_entity_decode()`, you don't need it.

Comment: no,its not working....sorry to inform i am getting select box data by calling ajax/jquery.